# Resetting an input to initial value when a search result is clicked with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-hide

I've a list on ng-repeat that displays a list of results from a $http query (bind to an input). I'd like both for the list to disappear when the user clicks on one of the results and for the initial empty value of the model to be restored. 
Basically, the functionality is as follows:

User searches term, list displays results, user clicks on result, list disappears, user clicks on input again to make another search, list with new results appear.

So far I've managed to make the list disappear, but not to make it appear again when the user makes another search.

Here's the relevant code:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="Research()"/>
  <ul ng-hide="clicked" ng-show="retype">
    <li ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="getDetails(result.id)">{{result.title}}</li>
  </ul>
```

And the JS:

```
function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
var get_results = function(name) {
  if (name) {
    $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=8').
      success(function(data3) {
        $scope.results = data3.results;
      });
  }
}
$scope.name = '';
$scope.$watch('name', get_results, true);


$scope.getDetails = function (id) {
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
    success(function(data) {
        $scope.artist = data;
    });
  $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=500').
    success(function(data2) {
        $scope.releases = data2.releases;
    });
  $scope.clicked = true;

}

function Research(){
  $scope.retype = true,
  $scope.name = '';
}
```

Plunkr is down, I'll make one as soon as possible. Any idea about what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Research function is unnecessary because you don't need `ng-show` and `ng-hide` same time...

secondly you set `clicked` to ok but never set it `false` again after your research done...

here is working [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/bB3SEN?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

I tidied up your code a little bit. Please note that the `div` is shown only when `artist` is defined. So when it is set to `undefined` by the `$scope.clear()` method, the mentioned `div` is hidden.

**Html part:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-focus="clear()"/>

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="result in results" ng-click="getDetails(result.id)">{{result.title}}</li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-show="artist">
        <h1>Artist</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>{{artist.name}}</li>
            <li>{{artist.release_url}}</li>
            <li>{{artist.uri}}</li>
            <li>{{artist.resource_url}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript part:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.name = undefined;
    $scope.artist = undefined;
    $scope.results = undefined;

    var search = function (name) {             
      if (name) {
        $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=8').
          success(function(data3) {
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });
      }        
    }    

    $scope.$watch('name', search, true);

    $scope.getDetails = function (id) {

      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.artist = data;
        });

      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=500').
        success(function(data2) {
            $scope.releases = data2.releases;
        });
    }

    $scope.clear = function () {
      $scope.name = undefined;
      $scope.artist = undefined;
      $scope.results = undefined;
    }
}
```

There is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd5uF/2/).

Comment: Used your answer to fix the issue! It was causing an unwanted effect (you couldn't have known as it was outside the code I pasted here), but I fixed it following your solution. Here's the Plunker in case you want to take a look. Also, I've realized a problem of usability, as sometimes the user selects the text inside the input without clicking into it, so aside from ng-click, I also used ng-focus to trigger the clear function.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4RppYo6QVkIGvqq0SD1Z?p=preview)

Comment: @EricMitjans it is even not you wanted or described in your question why you choose this as an answer?

Comment: @wickY26 I understood your answer wrong, rechecked it and also works in the Plunker, but not in my code for whatever reason :S

Comment: Found the bug, @wickY26, your answer works and is more simple and code efficient, u're right. What I don't know is which one of the two methods is more "best pratice"... anyway, thank u both for the help : ))

Answer (score 1):

Try using just one ng-hide or ng-show, instead of both. Since you never set `clicked` back to false, it is probably overriding the `retype`.
Both functions are two-way, so you can just use `ng-hide="clicked"`, and inside function Research, set $scope.clicked to false.